# List of dict - count occurences

Tags: python

I am trying to achieve,

Before:

```
dict = [{'name':'count', 'label':'Count'},{'name':'type', 'label':'Type'}, {'name':'count', 'label':'Count1'}]
```

After:

```
dict = [{'name':'count', 'label':'Count', 'count': 2},{'name':'type', 'label':'Type', 'count': 1}]
```

When tried to use :

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(dict)
```

It throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: btw, don't use `dict` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

Comment: Please explain the logic from `Before` to `After` to improve your odds of getting a good response.

Comment: btw, in your `Before:` you have: `'label':'Count1'`. Did you mean: `'label':'Count'`?

Comment: @Balaji Ambresh, I suppose it counts the same dicts, and updating a dict with number of counterparts

Comment: @JuiceFV Unless [quamrana] is right, your explanation would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with Counter, not very pythonic though:

```
from collections import Counter
d = [{'name': 'count', 'label': 'Count'}, {'name': 'type', 'label': 'Type'}, {'name': 'count', 'label': 'Count'}]

r = [dt.update({'count': count}) or dt for sub, count in Counter(map(lambda i: tuple(i.items()), d)).items() for dt in [dict(sub)]]
```

The r is:

```
[{'name': 'count', 'label': 'Count', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'type', 'label': 'Type', 'count': 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, dict cannot be keys to Counter. Because it's mutable. You need to convert your dict into an inmutable type.
exmaple:

```py
from collections import Counter
Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in dict)
```

*Note*: Your code seems to be wrong. There is a '1' after 'Count' in the last dict.

Comment: new_dicts = []
from builtins import dict
for value, count in counter.items():
    dictionary = dict(value)  # Convert the frozenset back to dict
    dictionary['count'] = count
    new_dicts.append(dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help

```py
dict=list({v['name']:v for v in [i for i in dict if i.update({'count':[a['name'] for a in dict].count(i['name'])})==None]}.values())
```